# How to lock down a filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know `me.filter ="filter"` sets the filter and `me.filteron = true` turns the filter on but what code in vba makes it so the user can't remove a filter once it's applied ?

Comment: Rather than applying a filter could you change the record source?

Comment: Absolutely, but I was just curious if it was possible.

Comment: I don't think so, unless you want to go to the trouble of customizing your menus.